# HTML5 Canvas eraser tool without overdraw image load to canvas

Tags: javascript, html, image, canvas, image-editing

I try to make a simple image editor for load image in a particular person's bill. I want to draw a line-loaded image(i want to cut some bill claim items using the pen tool, I gave the option eraser for editing purposes). I create canvas load images with pen and eraser tools. but I have some issues when eraser the draw line image content also delete. how do I avoid this problem?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Page Title</title>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<style type="text/css">
    body{ background-color: ivory; }

    canvas{border:1px solid red;}

</style>
</head>
<body>

<img id="scream" width="220" height="277" src="download.png" alt="The Scream">

<canvas id="canvas" width=300 height=500></canvas></br>
<button id="pen">Pen</button>
<button id="eraser">Eraser</button>

</body>
</html>
<script type="text/javascript">

var canvas=document.getElementById("canvas");
var ctx=canvas.getContext("2d");
var img = document.getElementById("scream");
ctx.drawImage(img, 10, 10, 300, 500);
var lastX;
var lastY;
var strokeColor="red";
var strokeWidth=5;
var mouseX;
var mouseY;
var canvasOffset=$("#canvas").offset();
var offsetX=canvasOffset.left;
var offsetY=canvasOffset.top;
var isMouseDown=false;


function handleMouseDown(e){
  mouseX=parseInt(e.clientX-offsetX);
  mouseY=parseInt(e.clientY-offsetY);

  // Put your mousedown stuff here
  lastX=mouseX;
  lastY=mouseY;
  isMouseDown=true;
}

function handleMouseUp(e){
  mouseX=parseInt(e.clientX-offsetX);
  mouseY=parseInt(e.clientY-offsetY);

  // Put your mouseup stuff here
  isMouseDown=false;
}

function handleMouseOut(e){
    
  mouseX=parseInt(e.clientX-offsetX);
  mouseY=parseInt(e.clientY-offsetY);

  // Put your mouseOut stuff here
  isMouseDown=false;
}

function handleMouseMove(e){
  mouseX=parseInt(e.clientX-offsetX);
  mouseY=parseInt(e.clientY-offsetY);

  // Put your mousemove stuff here
  if(isMouseDown){
    ctx.beginPath();
    if(mode=="pen"){
      ctx.globalCompositeOperation="source-over";
      ctx.moveTo(lastX,lastY);
      ctx.lineTo(mouseX,mouseY);
      ctx.stroke();     
    }else{
      ctx.globalCompositeOperation="destination-out";
      ctx.arc(lastX,lastY,8,0,Math.PI*2,false);
      ctx.fill();
    }
    lastX=mouseX;
    lastY=mouseY;
  }
}

$("#canvas").mousedown(function(e){handleMouseDown(e);});
$("#canvas").mousemove(function(e){handleMouseMove(e);});
$("#canvas").mouseup(function(e){handleMouseUp(e);});
$("#canvas").mouseout(function(e){handleMouseOut(e);});

var mode="pen";
$("#pen").click(function(){ mode="pen"; });
$("#eraser").click(function(){ mode="eraser"; });
</script>
```

Comment: You can't erase a canvas, you can only draw more things. Some of those things, like transparency, may seem like erasing, but that's just an illusion. (For example, drawing white on a white canvas may seem like erasing but it's more like using whiteout.) The upshot of this is that, when you draw over something, what was there before is lost. The usual solution is to track what draw actions where done previously and modify those. Then clear the canvas and redraw it using the modified set of actions.